# how can i open and close components with onClick and dispatch close on out click with redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

i create my reducers with createSlice in redux toolkit i declared my states

this is my store in ./root/app/store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import calendarReducer from '../features/calendarSlice'
import windowReducer from '../features/windowSlice'
import startReducer from '../features/startSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        calendar: calendarReducer,
        window: windowReducer,
        start: startReducer
    },
})
```

and this is my calendarSlice in ./root/features/calendarSlice.jsx

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    value: false
}

export const calendarSlice = createSlice({
    name: "calendar",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        openCalendar : (state) => {
            state.value = true
        },
        closeCalendar: (state) => {
            state.value = false
        },
        closeCalendarOnOtherLayoutsClick: (state) => {
            state.value = false
        }
        
    }
});

export const {openCalendar, closeCalendar} = calendarSlice.actions
export default calendarSlice.reducer
```

and this is my startSlice in ./root/features/startSlice.jsx

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    value: false
}

export const startSlice = createSlice({
    name:'start',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        openStart: (state) => {
            state.value = true
        },
        closeStart: (state) => {
            state.value = false
        }
    }
});

export const {openStart, closeStart} = startSlice.actions
export default startSlice.reducer
```

and below code is my main component with imported component such as calendar and start
my code works perfect when click on clock calendar component state = true and open when click again calendar get close but when i click on calendar it close himself i want active this features in redux reducer with actions.
can anybody answer how can i do this project in new redux.

```
import styles from "./dock.module.scss";
import { useRef } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { openCalendar,closeCalendar  } from '../../../features/calendarSlice'
import { openStart, closeStart } from '../../../features/startSlice'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Start from '../start/Start'
import Calendar from "./Calendar";
const Dock = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const leftDock = useRef(null)
  const centerDock = useRef(null)
  const rightDock = useRef(null)
  const calendarState = useSelector((state) => state.calendar.value)
  const startState = useSelector((state) => state.start.value)

 const calendarHandler = () => {
   if(calendarState == true){
     dispatch(closeCalendar())
   }else {
     dispatch(openCalendar())
   }
 }
 const startHandler = () => {
  if(startState == true){
    dispatch(closeStart())
  }else {
    dispatch(openStart())
  }
}
 const dockClickHandler = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation()
  dispatch(closeCalendar())
  
 }
  return (
    <div  className={styles.dockContainer}>
  
      <div onClick={dockClickHandler} ref={leftDock} className={styles.left}></div>

      <div onClick={dockClickHandler} ref={centerDock}  className={styles.center}>
        <div onClick={startHandler} className={styles.iconContainer}>
          <div className={styles.icon}>
            <Image src="/icon/home.png" width={24} height={24} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.iconContainer}>
          <div className={styles.icon}>
            <Image src="/icon/search.png" width={24} height={24} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.iconContainer}>
          <div className={styles.icon}>
            <Image src="/icon/settings.png" width={24} height={24} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.iconContainer}>
          <div className={styles.icon}>
            <Image src="/icon/explorer.png" width={24} height={24} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.iconContainer}>
          <div className={styles.icon}>
            <Image src="/icon/store.png" width={24} height={24} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.iconContainer}>
          <div className={styles.icon}>
            <Image src="/icon/spotify.png" width={24} height={24} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div ref={rightDock} onClick={calendarHandler} 
      className={styles.right}>
        12:00
      <Calendar calendarState={calendarState} />
      </div>
      <Start startState={startState} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dock;

const calendar = {
  position: "absolute",
  width: "21rem",
  height: "300px",
  maxWidth: "500px",
  maxHeight: "500px",
  right: "12px",
  bottom: "calc(48px + 12px)",
  borderRadius: "8px",
  backgroundColor: "red",
  zIndex: "9999",
  color: "black",
  overflow: "hidden",
  transition: "1s ease",
};
```

[a view of open calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llm73.png)

[here it's my issue when i have start open and click on calendar start should be close without dispatch confilicts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dJ0a.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add payload in your slices then dispatch your value in your component

**calendarSlice.jsx**

```
export const calendarSlice = createSlice({
    name: "calendar",
    initialState: {
        value: false
    },
    reducers: {
        openCalendar: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload
        },
        // or with destructuring action
        openCalendar: (state, { payload }) => {
            state.value = payload
        },
        
    }
});
```

**your component.jsx**

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   dispatch(openCalendar(!value));
};
```

Check my simple demo here : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-foqht7?file=src%2Fredux%2Ffeatures%2FcalendarSlice.js)